# Python IDLE 2.7 won't execute file until I hit "enter"

Tags: python, python-idle

For some reason when I select "run module", IDLE won't run the first line of code until I press "enter". It's not a huge problem for this type of program, but I'm confused why this is happening. Can anyone clear this up for me? Here's the code:

```
print("Please think a number between 0 and 100!")
guess = 50
upper = 100
lower = 0
status = ""
while status != "c":
    print("Is your secret number ") + str(guess) + ("?")
    print ("Lower: ") + str(lower)
    print ("Upper: ") + str(upper)
    status = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate     the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
    if status == "h":
        upper = guess
        guess = guess - (guess - lower)/2
    elif status == "l":
        lower = guess
        guess = guess + (upper - guess)/2
    elif status == "c":
        break
    else:
    print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
print("Game over. Your secret number was: ") + str(guess)
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: On some platforms/versions, if the module has been edited since last save, the "Save Before Run or Check" dialog sometimes pops up behind another window. It's still active, so when you hit "enter" that triggers the "OK" button, but you don't see it. Is it possible that this is your case? (I've seen this on OS X 10.6, with python.org Python 2.6, but Apple Tk. The only fix is to either stick with Apple's Python or install ActiveState Tk, as python.org's download page explains. But presumably if it can happen there, it can happen on other platforms.)

Answer (score 1):

See http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/execution.html (see section 1.9.2). It's a bug that occurs sometimes if the previous program was interrupted.

Comment: Ah this makes perfect sense. That was exactly the issue. Thank you!